# vNext build on TFS 2015 hangs on MSBuild step and produces no log files

Tags: git, tfs, build, continuous-integration, tfs-2015

We have recently upgraded from on-premises TFS2013 to 2015 Update1, and we have set up a VSO Build Agent.

I am now trying to set up a test (continuous integration) vNext build for a solution in our Git repository, but the **builds are not running** and **not producing any logs**.

The build properties have been set up to indicate the correct Git repo, and the following three have been added to Variables: VSO_GIT_USERNAME, VSO_GIT_PASSWORD, DNXPath. MSBuild is the only step added to the build at the present.

[image: Showing MSBuild Step]

Pushed commits result in builds being triggered as expected, but when a build is triggered, **it just hangs** "Waiting for console output from an agent":

[image: Waiting for build agent]

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the agent:

- it is shown as running (checked in services.msc)
- it has no SSL dependencies
- port 9191 has been added to Inbound rules in TFS server firewall
- the agent is running with "Project Collection Build Service" privileges
- the agent appears green in Web access:

[image]

When I cancel the build and download log files, the zip file is empty.

The same happens when I queue a build manually (against a specific commit #): no build runs and no log files.

**What should I do/check to either make my build progress or make it produce log files?**

Can anybody suggest a way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solution found! In my particular case I set up port 9191 using Firewall interface (Windows Server 2012 R2), and the inbound rule for it looked nice and active. But it lied.

When I asked a good colleague of mine, Marc, to check if the port was really ok, he ran **Get-NetFirewallPortFilter** in PowerShell on the TFS machine and my port was missing from the list!

The solution he suggested was to run the following PowerShell script (since Firewall was playing up):

```
   $port = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FWOpenPort
   $port.Port = 9191
   $port.Name = 'TFS CI Port:9191'
   $port.Enabled = $true

   $fwMgr = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FwMgr
   $profile = $fwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile
   $profile.GloballyOpenPorts.Add($port)
```

Once this was run, an inbound rule for port 9191 appeared in Firewall inbound rules.

I then manually queued the build, and for the first time saw it fail (not hang!), and with log files at that! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the account that the agent is run under is in the "Agent Pool Service Account" role.
2. Make sure the queue is provisioned in the collection ( https://your-tfs-server:8080/tfs/your-collection/_admin/_AgentQueue ). If not - select "New queue.." and select the existing queue.
3. Make sure you deploy the Windows build agent by exactly following [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows).
4. Try to change a domain account which is a member of the Build Agent Service Accounts group and belongs to "Agent Pool Service Account" role, to see whether the agent would work or not.
5. Re-deploy the windows agent.

Comment: Cece, thank you for getting back. Turned out it was a Firewall inbound rule creation rule, possibly Windows 2012 R2 specific.