# TFS vNext Builds won't start

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2015 Update 1 installed and a Build agent up and running
[image: Agent]

The agent machine has all Windows SDKs installed (at least the .net parts) plus Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I have a dedicated domain account ssvc_tfs that is local administrator on the agent machine, the agent is installed as service running under this account.

However, all vNext builds I queue are immediatly failing with the following screen:
[image]

Notice the messages "not found" and "Ran for 0 seconds". Please ignore "(no queue)" since it was deleted during one of my desperate tries after triggering this build. I have other failed build showing the correct queue, so this is not an issue.

I stripped the build definition down to "open cmd and execute ipconfig.exe" only, but still, it fails immediatly.

Tried to reinstall the agent, adding and removing permissions, rebooting all, no change. Can someone point me in the right direction where to look? The build agent's diag log is no help, since it just reports happy polls for messages:

```
12:58:26.942176 MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - No message retrieved from Session: 36896cc5-c8f4-4f7f-b703-750bc364f397
12:58:26.942176 MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - Getting message from Session: 36896cc5-c8f4-4f7f-b703-750bc364f397
12:59:16.989090 MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - message received.
12:59:16.989090 MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - No message retrieved from Session: 36896cc5-c8f4-4f7f-b703-750bc364f397
12:59:16.989090 MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - Getting message from Session: 36896cc5-c8f4-4f7f-b703-750bc364f397
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the account that the agent is run under is in the "Agent Pool Service Account" role.
2. Make sure the queue is provisioned in the collection ( https://your-tfs-server:8080/tfs/your-collection/_admin/_AgentQueue ). If not - select "New queue.." and select the existing queue.
3. Make sure you deploy the Windows build agent by exactly following [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows).
4. Try to change a domain account which is a member of the Build Agent Service Accounts group and belongs to "Agent Pool Service Account" role, to see whether the agent would work or not.
5. Check the Firewall inbound rule, check [vNext build on TFS 2015 hangs on MSBuild step and produces no log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315100/vnext-build-on-tfs-2015-hangs-on-msbuild-step-and-produces-no-log-files/36330270#36330270)

Comment: It turned out to be a permission problem, as you mentioned in step 4. Thanks for your detailed answer.