# "The build has been queued and is waiting to start" but never start building

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

[image]

There is no issue with agent and its green. When I queue new build, the text in console displays forever **"Waiting for console output from an agent...".** After the maximum time limit of build definition, it stops and build failed message appears.

Where is the issue? build not starts? Any help in this regard is required. Thanks

Comment: does the agent state change from waiting ever? do you have any demands on your build that is not met by the agent?

Comment: Paste your code that gives this output.

Comment: Does your build agent have capabilities that satisfy all of the demands of the builds? On the "General" tab of the build, you'll see the required capabilities.

Comment: The same code and build definition is working fine on some other server but here it remain waited till the maximum time limit.

There is simple mvc web project, nothing changed in it, and it works fine on some other server.

Comment: Build definition is simplest, just unchecked the restore nuget packages.

Comment: Similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315100/vnext-build-on-tfs-2015-hangs-on-msbuild-step-and-produces-no-log-files

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the build agent service to see whether it is running.
2. Make sure the account that the agent is run under is in the "Agent Pool Service Account" role.
3. Try to change a domain account which is a member of the Build Agent Service Accounts group and belongs to "Agent Pool Service Account" role, to see whether the agent would work or not.

Answer (score 0):

It likely a connectivity issue. This just happened to me.